# Como capturar click en un marcador maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Buenas, ¿como puedo hacer para capturar el click sobre un marcador en maps?

Como veis hice una prueba (varias) pero no es correcto.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//JS para trabajar con el mapa en el apartado de gimnasios.
function localizacion(posicion){

    // Obtenemos nuestras coordenadas.
    var latitud = posicion.coords.latitude;
    var longitud = posicion.coords.longitude;

    //Generamos el mapa que muestre nuestra actual posición
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: latitud, lng: longitud},
        zoom: 14
    });

    //Generamos el marcadores para señalar una posición
    var markerMiPosicion = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: latitud, lng: longitud},
        title:"Mi actual ubicación"
    });

    // Mostramos los marcadores en el mapa.
    markerMiPosicion.setMap(map);

    // CAPTURAR CLICK MARKER
    $(markerMiPosicion).click(function(){
        alert('texto prueba');
    });

}

// En caso de no poder geolocalizar hay que tener un mensaje de error (o acción)
function error (){
    alert('No se puede obtener tu ubicación actual')
    // un error a valorar es que el usuario no permite la geoloc, code:1
}


// Ahora empleamos todo lo declarado anteriormente.
// Comprobamos si el navegador soporta la geolocalización
if(navigator.geolocation){
    //Caso SI soporta geolocalización. Ejecuto la API y llamo a mis funciones.
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(localizacion, error);
}
else{
    //Caso NO soporta geolocalización
    alert ('Navegador NO soporta geolocalización');
}
});
```

Salud!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { }
```

lo que quieras hacer va dentro

Comment: Me Habia equivocado

Comment: Con eso me funciona muchas gracias, pero una pregunta por si lo sabes, ¿mediante jquery se podría? me refiero, empleando--> $().click...